# auto declare helpers functions with clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm searching a way to keep my helpers functions to the bottom of the file, without declare them all at the top.

One solution should be to write a "declare-helpers" function that grab the names of all functions create via defn- macro in the current file and wrap them in a declare call.

Here I'm asking about the better way to grab those names.

*** edit ***

I know this is bad practice but, the following code seems to do what I want

Note that it apply only to helpers function define with the "dehfn" macro

```
;define helper function
(defmacro dehfn [name & body]
  `(defn- ~name ~@body))

(defmacro declare-helpers []
  `(declare ~@(map symbol 
                   (re-seq #"(?<=dehfn\s)[a-zA-Z+!\-_?0-9*~#@''`/.$=]*(?=\s)" 
                           (slurp (str "src/" *file*))))))
```

Now you can do that:

```
(declare-helpers)

(defn hello-user [name] (greet name))

(dehfn greet [name] (str "Hello my dear " name))
```

Comment: Why would you even want to do that? Writing functions at the top that are used at the bottom is a straightforward win for readability. After all, people still read code from top to bottom. Just because functions are not API exposed or not publics of the ns they aren't less important, possibly even more important as they are a substantial part of what the reader is interested in when he opens the source file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible. No macro can know about code written later in the file than the macro invocation, since there are no vars for it to inspect yet. Just practice reading files "upside down": Clojure is not the only language in which the public and/or important stuff is often at the bottom.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that the most of interpreted languages have a similar structure (important stuff at the bottom)?

Comment: This is also the same order as mathematical exposition - lemmas come before proofs.

Comment: can't I just get the current file as a string form whithin the "declare helpers" macro-or-function and then grab names with regular expressions?

Comment: Then you'd have two problems...You *could* wrap your entire file contents in a macro and walk the source, but don't. You *could* use emacs to do the manipulation every time you edit the file, but don't.

Comment: ok i see, i was just curious, i knew it sounds dirty right from the beginning.